# How can I show the 'loading' pop up after I click on the submit button for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom, jquery-mobile

I'm using the jQuery Mobile javascript library. In my form, I can't seem to acheive what this [form](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html) is doing. After I click on the Submit button. I want the user to see the 'loading' pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Imporant

Please note the following comment by [Michael Kariv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209387/michael-kariv):

> deprecated, at least in jqm 1.3.2, may be earlier. looking into the code reveals

```
showPageLoadingMsg: function( theme, msgText, textonly ) {
    $.mobile.loading('show', theme, msgText, textonly );
}
```

The original answer was:

---

```
$('#yourform').submit(function(){
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); // http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html
})
```

Hiding the message again: `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();`

Comment: Is there a call back to check if that submit is completed so I know when I can call '$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();'?

Comment: yep i am submitting via ajax.

Comment: Use your AJAX callback then! `$.post(url, data, function(){ $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); });`

Comment: deprecated, at least in jqm 1.3.2, may be earlier. looking into the code reveals  showPageLoadingMsg: function( theme, msgText, textonly ) {
   $.mobile.loading( 'show', theme, msgText, textonly );
  },